# Any API for repairing or spliting MP3 files

Tags: c#, api, split, mp3, repair

I'm using nAudio to splite MP3 files. but some times it throws:

`FormatException("Not a recognised MP3 block");`

I read [this discussion](http://naudio.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=46568). But it dosen't help me! So i think it should be a problem in my MP3 file. How ever players can play it properly.

So, What should I do? Do [Lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) or any other APIs can help me to repair it? Note that I need to split a MP3 file, So if there is any good API, please introduce to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php)! It's awesome! :D

Comment: indeed Mp3splt is cool !  Thanks !